# Directory.Getfiles() reads only the first file in the folder

Tags: c#, .net

HI I need to read all the files in a directory. The code below reads only the first file even if 10 files are present in the folder. It does not throw any exception. Why is it not printing the other files name? Any help appreciated.

```
string[] txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Sample", "*.txt");
foreach (string item in txtFiles)
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(item);
    if (contents.Contains("testing"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

In D:\Sample I have 10 sample files which contain the word testing in them. But it reads only Sample1.txt and does not read the rest.

```
Output:
Sample1.txt
```

[image]

Comment: I think your diagnosis is off. Are all the files in that directory or are they in subdirectories? Is the casing always "testing" or might it be "Testing"? There are a lot of variables here.

Comment: after this line : `Console.WriteLine(File);` put ` Console.WriteLine(---------);` and see what you will have

Comment: Why do you want to make your life difficult? Change the name of the variables to something different from keywords and class names (array, File )

Comment: can you show us your folder maybe with a screenshot?

Comment: Well, this code cannot be compiled File is a class in the System.IO namespace and declaring a variable with that name you are obscuring the File class, so ReadAllText could not be called on a string. You can't have a variable with that name. Please show your real code and tell us if you have any try/catch around this code

Comment: The only way you might be able to compile this code is if you actually have a local class defined named `File` that you created and it happened to have a method called `ReadAllText` that takes a parameter of type `YourApplication.File`. And you don't happen to be importing the `System.IO` namespace. However I'm doubtful this is the case

Comment: @icemanind that would be really a big surprise. Probably we have a better chance to win the lottery. However I have seen much worse things.

Comment: @Steve - You are right. But I couldn't help but be a wise-guy there!

Answer (score 0):

Please change you File variable as file as below and try.

```
 string[] array = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Sample", "*.txt");
        foreach (string file in array)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
            if (contents.Contains("testing"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
        }
```